# How to activate environment created with virtualenv in a PC where Anaconda is also installed?

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv

I have anaconda installed and multiple virtual environments created within Anaconda. However I recently installed virtualenv using '`pip install virtualenv`' at the windows command prompt.
I created a new virtual environment using '`python -m virtualenv new_env'` which does not exists in conda virtual environment. When try to activate 'new_env' using '`activate new_env`' at the command prompt, I get an error 'Could not find conda environment: 'new_env''. This means it's still looking at conda environment.
How can I activate 'env_new' ?. I don't want to remove Anaconda which I did on another PC just get virtualend to work.

Comment: it means activate is pointing to conda by default. to activate `new_env` try `cd path_to_new_env; source activate`

Comment: You mean finding activate folder ?

Comment: cd to new_env folder

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, virtualenv creates a .bat/.ps1 file, so you should run `new_env\Scripts\activate` instead (per the virtualenv [documentation on the activate script](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/legacy/userguide.html#activate-script)).

Just run `activate`, without an extension, so the right file will get used regardless of whether you're using cmd.exe or PowerShell.

Checkout this below link also
https://youtu.be/iUy6BYVWEbA